# .click handler and .toggle not working

Tags: jquery, html

**Solved** This is a very anticlimactic solution, but the jQuery library being used was not the correct one for these functions... I went to google's hosted libraries page and found the one for jquery 1.11.3 amd everything now works fine. I appreciate your time everyone!

Ok, this is kind of weird because I got the code to work when I use an editor and the accessed it through my browser with XAMPP, but when I write it in Dreamweaver, it does not seem to work. Can anyone spot a difference or know why something like this would happen? The link will nicely slide up and down when using the Editra code, but nothing will happen when I click contact in DW. Appreciate the help!

Relevant HTML (Dreamweaver):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" style= "position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px; background-color:#646464;;">
</canvas>

<div id="nav">
 <ul>
    <li><a id="contact" style="position:relative;" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a id= "other" href="#">Other Work</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

```
<p id="email"><a href="mailto:someone@gmail.com" style="position:relative;">someone</a></p>
```

Relevant jQuery (Dreamweaver):

```
$('#contact').click(function(){$('#email').toggle('slow', 'linear')});
```

Relevant HTML (Editra):

```
<canvas id="c" style= "position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px; background-color:#646464;;">
</canvas>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="toggle" style="position:relative;" href="#">toggle</a>   </li>
        <li><a id="other" href = "#">other</a></li>    
    </ul>
</div>
<p id="toggled"><a href="mailto:someone@gmail.com" style="position:relative;">someone</a></p>
```

Relevant jQuery (Editra):

```
$('#toggle').click(function(){$('#toggled').toggle('slow', 'linear')});
```

For the Editra part, that is basically all there is, I was simply testing out the method. There is more to the Dreamweaver side, but nothing that SHOULD play a part in this code. That being said, if you know more that I do and think there could be something outside of the code I have shown you, I will gladly provide that for you.

[Here is a fiddle of the DW code](https://jsfiddle.net/sgeugyfk/)

[Here is a fiddle of the Editra Code](https://jsfiddle.net/gvv3gas0/)

Comment: Your Dreamweaver HTML lacks a reference to jQuery.  So either that's part of it, or you're not showing us truly comparable HTML.

Comment: Sorry about that, it does have the reference. I have now edited it to include that. There is a lot more JS that is doing its job in the full document, so that wasn't the issue.

Comment: Make sure you wrap the clicks in `$(function() { .... });`. I think you are trying to attach the handlers before the html is there.

Comment: changed  
   `$('#contact').click(...)`   to 

    `$(document.ready(function(){....});` 

and still nothing :(

Comment: Please do not edit your solution into your question. You can simply answer your own question with your solution.

Comment: I have now done so, @Mike McCaughan. But I am going to leave that bold solved up at the top so people will immediately know that there is no purely coding error and it was simply a mistake of not having the right library

Comment: Just a suggestion... but I would leave dreamweaver behind you.  ; )

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed adding the jQuery in the DW code:

```
    <canvas id="c" style= "position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px; background-color:#646464;;">
    </canvas>

    <div id="nav">
     <ul>
        <li><a id="contact" style="position:relative;" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a id= "other" href="#">Other Work</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <p id="email"><a href="mailto:someone@gmail.com" style="position:relative;">someone</a></p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>    
      $(function(){
        $('#contact').click(function(){$('#email').toggle('slow', 'linear')});

      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed adding in the reference to the snippet, but it was there. Side question though, must jQuery be contained in a function like that?

Comment: @RM3 Yes, it must! It's for the jQuery runs after all page is loaded

Comment: How about wrapping jQuery code in `$(function(){ ... });`?

Comment: i tried both `$(document.ready(function(){....});` and `$(function(){...});` to no avail :(

Answer (score 0):

When asking a question, you can first break it down into a simple version to sort out what the problem may be at a low level first. Make a jsFiddle or something for us to use.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/oufghL0b/)

### HTML

```
<button id="contact">contact...</button>

<div id="email" style='display: none;'>email... ?</div>
```

### CSS

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#contact').on('click', function() {
        // alert('test');
        // $('#email').toggle();
        $('#email').fadeToggle();
    });

});
```

Then you can use this simple version to work up and see what it is in your larger code-base.

Comment: You are right about the fiddle, that was a slip on my part. Here is a fiddle, copied straight from my DW document where the code is not working. https://jsfiddle.net/sgeugyfk/

Comment: Include jQuery on the left of your fiddle.  : )

Comment: ...what an oversight on my side haha. That did the trick but unfortunately is has still not solved my main issue. I think it has something to do with the canvas element no allowing the links to be displayed properly, but I don't have much to back that up with

Comment: I think you need to observe a parent and then watch for a click - since the canvas probably isn't noted by the document ready...  `$('body').on('click', '#email', function() ...`

Answer (score 0):

Solved This is a very anticlimactic solution, but the jQuery library being used was not the correct one for these functions... I went to google's hosted libraries page and found the one for jquery 1.11.3 and everything now works fine. Nothing was wrong or needed to change in the actual code, I only needed to do this one step. I appreciate your time everyone!

Solution was to add this(the 1.11.3 library):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Before I only had this(the 2.1.3 library):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're not using BOTH, are you?

Comment: Yes, I was using both... but after seeing your disgust I will be removing one. I take it some conflicts can arise out of using both of them? Also, to you dreamweaver comment, can I ask why and what is a good replacement? I am still in the 30 day free trial period of it but was seriously considering getting a subscription.

Comment: HA, I didn't mean to sound disgusted. I DID, however wanted to check and make sure that you understood what those things were. They are different versions of a library. Libraries are collections of useful functions. In this case however, they could and most likely do conflict as some of those functions are the same / yet updated. I strongly suggest you get a subscription to front-end-masters website of tutorials - and begin using a proper plain-old text-editor ~ instead of dreamweaver. While a successful and admirable attempt to bridge the gap between page-maker and code... I advise against.